How to fix glitches in facet orientation visualization
Problem
I created a SLDPRT model on SolidWorks, exported it as a PLY file, and imported it into Blender. Ideally, the face normals should oriented toward the outside, but the facet orientation is shown as a mix of blue and red. For example, in the image below, the facet orientations of the dish antenna are partially red.

However, when it is zoomed in, the orientation is shown as blue:

What I tried

Recalculation of face normals: I selected all the faces by A and recalculated the face normals by "Mesh -> Normal -> Recalculate Outside." It didn't fix the problem.

Merge duplicated vertices: Press M and merge vertices by distance. I tried several distance values, but no vertices were merged until the model collapsed.

Check the non-manifold mesh: "Select -> Select All by Trait -> Non-Manifold." The model doesn't have any non-manifold mesh.


I suspect the model somehow overlaps facets, but I don't know how to confirm and repair it. I didn't use any tricky techniques that would cause duplicated facets in Solidworks—only the Extrusion, Revolve, and Mirror operators. Could anyone give me some advice? Thank you.
I have attached the Blender file below:


Is it actually causing a problem? - I suspect you're just seeing flashes of the back face of the 'other side' of your object. You can see the same on the solar panels if you move them around a bit.

I think it's safe to ignore. It's just a glitch in Blender I think. There's nothing wrong with the model.

@HarryMcKenzie It's an incorrect clip start setting. It's not just a glitch in Blender, all OpenGL / DirectX applications have these limitations.

@GordonBrinkmann Thanks for sharing :) but I still see red even with 0.1m

@HarryMcKenzie Really? I don't, see the screenshot in my answer (and obviously it solved the problem). It's a well documented issue, glitches in perspective view are usually caused by incorrect Clip Start values, in orthographic view it is usually caused by Clip End values. It is even explained in the Blender manual, I just couldn't find a good answer here to mark it as duplicate.

@GordonBrinkmann Interesting. Could you share the blender documentation of the glitch also in your post for others to read as well. Here's the glitch for me in 4.2 also at 0.1m but reduced glitchiness. https://imgur.com/a/XYJ7Nd8

These kinds of glitches are typical for having a too low Clip Start value in the 3D Viewport. Extremely low values will make these glitches also visible without the Face Orientation overlay - but when this is enabled, it becomes visbile even quicker.
Your setting is Clip Start = 0.01 m and looks like this:

Increasing the value to 0.1 m gives this result:

The strange shading that is left is because you have shaded the object smooth.

It works like a charm! Thank you for your answer!

In addition to Gordon Brinkmann's correct answer to adjust your Clip Start and Clip End values in the 3D Viewport, there's another setting you may need to adjust if you are using the new version of EEVEE in Blender 4.2 or newer and your Scene Unit Scale is smaller than 1 (such as when using 0.01 for exporting to Unreal Engine).

Go to Render Properties > Viewport > Pixel Size, and change it from
"Automatic" to "1x".

When combined with the correct Clip Start and End values, this will fix the Z-fighting and flickering when overlays like Face Orientation or Face Sets are used.


Thanks for the valuable information!

@Ogiad You're very welcome! :-) I discovered that the Blender Team considers this a bug so it will eventually be addressed in a future release: https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/124013
